# Signal Crayfish in North Northamptonshire

Tags: fishing

I am applying for a licence to catch signal crayfish, but being asked what stretch of water I will be using. As this will be first time trying this, I wanted to know if anyone can recommend anywhere in the North Northamptonshire area, & border with Rutland/Leicestershire.

Thanks